# Why can't I install php extension by pecl?

Tags: php, memcached, pecl

I use cento-7-mini. first I install some dependences by yum, and I compile php-5.5.36:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php \
--enable-fpm \
--enable-opcache \
--enable-mysqlnd \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-sockets \
--with-fpm-user=www-data \
--with-fpm-group=www-data \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-gd \
--with-zlib \
--with-curl \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-openssl
```

then I copy the php.ini-production to /usr/local/php/etc/php.ini, and

```
mv /usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.default /usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm
```

then I config my nginx server and I can use phpinfo() test it successfully. that's no problem I think.

I want to install some extension, for example memcahe.

```
pecl install memcache
```

then I can see:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-     20121212/memcache.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/memcache-3.0.8
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=memcache.so" to php.ini
```

then I add

```
extension=/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so
```

to the file /usr/local/php/etc/php.ini

finnaly, I restart my php-fpm and nginx, but I can't see the memcache extension in the phpinfo page.

I have seen many article but I can't find answers.